# jQuery: Clicking anywhere to remove class, without using $('body').on('click'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove all active classes when clicking anywhere on the screen, but if a clicked element has the .dropdown class, I would also want to toggle the .active class into that element.

```
// remove all .active classes when clicked anywhere
hide = true;
$('body').on("click", function () {
    if (hide) $('.dropdown').removeClass('active');
    hide = true;
});

// add and remove .active
$('body').on('click', '.dropdown', function () {

    var self = $(this);

    if (self.hasClass('active')) {
        $('.dropdown').removeClass('active');
        return false;
    }

    $('.dropdown').removeClass('active');

    self.toggleClass('active');
    hide = false;
});
```

I have this working with the above but I'm worried capturing a body click is overkill, and unnecessary. Is there a better solution?

[jsiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JPE4M/) - I've set several li's to the .active class, if you click around you will see they get removed. Clicking an li will trigger `toggleClass('active')`, whilst still removing all .active classes.

Answer (score 2):

you could try doing:

```
$('body').on("click", function (ev) {
    if( $(ev.target).hasClass('.dropdown') ) {
        //you clicked on .dropdown element, do something
    }
    else {
        //you clicked somewhere other than dropdown element
    }
});
```

Comment: I would change this slightly to be `if ($(ev.target).hasClass('dropdown active')) { ... }`. This way if there is more than one dropdown, clicking a second one will close the first in addition to expanding the second.